# How to write markdown language in HTML language?

Tags: html, markdown, ejs, hexo

`#` (and `##` and `###`) in md files has the meaning of header 1 (2, 3).

This md (markdown) header is used by a table of content widget I developed.

I want to use a md header (written as `#`) that is defined in ejs (template engine) html layout file.
How to write `#` in ejs (html) language so that it is also used by TOC widget same way as `#` in markdown md file?

To be more clear:

The `#` in markdown md file language is the same as `<%= header %>` when written in ejs (html) language? I am looking how to write `#` in EJS (html) language.
For example, it could be something like this maybe (I do not know, but just to illustrate my question): `#` in markdown language  equals `<%= header %>` in ejs (html) ?????

Apparently, my question is still not clear.
It is simple: How to write `#` (markdown language) in ejs (html) language so that the code from the ejs (html) file is parsed the same way as `#` in markdown?
It

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [marked package](https://github.com/chjj/marked) for that. Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var content = $('.my-md').html();
  $('.my-md').html(marked(content));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.6/marked.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <div class="my-md">
# Hello world
This is ** a simple test ** .
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where I am supposed to put the first part of the code? (JS newbie here.)

Comment: Please Google it, you will find resources like: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-javascript-to-html